# How do I change the color of the current line highlighting in gdb tui mode?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to change the highlighting of the current line in gdb from white to another color, or remove it and only use the '>' as an indicator. As you can see in the picture below some of the text is kind of hard to read when the current line is highlighted in white.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3u8O.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why did you tag this c?  It's a gdb configuration issue (and IMHO off-topic; ask Super User instead).

Comment: I don't think you can set it directly.  `tui_source_window_base::show_source_line()` is what renders the source code, and if it's a break point the function `tui_set_reverse_mode()` is called which swaps foreground and background.  `show style` tells you how to style things, but I don't see an obvious candidate source code.  You might have to define a color function in .gdbinit.  See https://github.com/gdbinit/Gdbinit/blob/master/gdbinit