# gdb tui: How to change the style of the "current line" bar?

Tags: gdb

I'm using gdb 10.2 in a gnome-terminal (on Ubuntu 20.04 running in WSL2), where gnome-terminal is configured to follow the system theme.

In `tui` mode, if the current line is indicated by a black bar. Function calls are formatted with black foreground text, rendering them unreadable:

[image: function names are unreadable in gdb tui]

**Already tried**

- `set style source off`: The current line is now readable, but source color coding is now (obviously) disabled
- `set style function foreground white`: No effect
- Configure gnome terminal to not follow the system theme: The terminal switches to "dark mode": The background now becomes black, the bar turns white. The function names are readable, but the legibility of many of the differently colored things is reduced.
- [Possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73737931/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-current-line-highlighting-in-gdb-tui-mode)

At this point, disabling source highlighting is workable, but suboptimal. Tips are most welcome!

Comment: Some time ago there was a [patch submitted](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb-patches/2020-June/169544.html) which made it possible to disable syntax highlighting for the current line only, but it was never merged.

Comment: Note that this patch was [recently merged](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=92c1d07de5f1d82421fcb78331d1e7c70a24ff23), so style disabling of the current line will be possible in the next release (and is actually now the default).